# iPad Simulator on macbook pro color much more vibrant than actual ipad

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I'm a little bit of a graphics nut, but I'm trying to figure out why the colors on my iPad simulator on my macbook pro seem much much more vibrant than they do on my actual iPad 2. Does anyone have any experience with this.

Or is there anything that i can do to help them seem much more vibrant than they currently are?

Thanks.

James.

Comment: Because they are different displays. [Color calibration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_calibration) would be the solution if it were possible on the iPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, it might be because they are physically different screens. Color matching is extremely difficult with different LCD manufacturers, backlights, etc… That's why it's always important to test on the device.

Now, if you are seeing a different colors in Photoshop and the actual device, I'd point out that iOS devices don't use [ICC Profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICC_profile) for color matching. But neither does the iPhone simulator so that theory is out if the simulator is different than the device.

Here's more info: http://ipadportfolioapp.com/howto/advancedUse/colorManagement

*Edit:*
Also, what display profile are you using on your MacBook Pro? (System Preferences > Displays > Color). Mine just uses Color LCD. If you have something else here, that might explain the difference. You can even try calibrating your MacBook screen here. Keep in mind that it could just be a difference between physical displays

Answer (score 0):

As other's have answered, the displays differ, but could be better if you could color calibrate both displays. Unfortunately, iOS give you no color calibration options, so you can just adjust the calibration of the Mac's display to get close to the iPad.

Using the Mac OS X supplied color calibrator in the Displays System Preference I'm able to get the simulator to show colors very close to my iPad 2's display. Just follow the steps. I used a gamma of 2.2 and a white point of D65, which seem to match my iPad, but you can play with those setting while comparing devices to get what works best with your iPad and Mac.

My last step is to adjust the brightness of the iPad to visually match the simulator on the color calibrated Mac monitor.

Answer (score -3):

Do you check the brigth of the screen?

or could be that your iPad screen is yellow?

[Apple iPad 2 suffers from yellow screen tint?](http://www.t3.com/news/apple-ipad-2-suffers-from-yellow-screen-tint)